# How to display data in vertically in different columns in SSRS Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an ssrs report which display data in a table just like image1.

image1 (Vertical)

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
```

I need to display data vertically in one table with different columns to avoid extra pages. Just like image2.

image2

```
abcd     IJKL    qrst
efgh    MNOP      uvwx
```

Currently I have tried matrix control with column group but it is displaying data like image3.

image3:

```
abcd
efgh
     ijkl
     mnop
           qrst
           uvwx
```

Below are the group expression.
Column Group : =ceiling(rownumber(nothing)/15)(for 15 records in  columns)
Why its not coming parallel like this :

```
abcd ijkl qrst
efgh mnop uvwx
```

Can anyone help me how to display it like above?
Note : I am new member of stack overflow that's why I can't add Images.I typed table contents and its showing horizontally.but all data is one below the other and I have only one column.
Thanks!

Comment: Its hard to understand, explain what you are exactly trying to do. Instead of using words like vertical, horizontal etc

Comment: I have only one column name as customer name with 40 rows or based on criteria. I want to display report as 10 records in one column ,next 10 records in 2nd column till last record.Basically split data over the columns instead of showing in one to avoid pages and it will be easy to read also.Hope this makes sense now.Thanks

Comment: how about other columns, is it same for id columns aswel ?

Comment: I have only one column name as Customer Name. I just want to display Customer names in above format as shown in my question

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder if you open up the report's properties you can specify the number of columns the data displays in.  Setting `Columns` to 3 should get you the desired output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! I could not see above option in my report   .I am using matrix in SSRS and getting Name of customer from customer dataset (using sql query with some criteria) to get exact name of customer names. In my question I have mentioned how Its displaying and how I want.

Comment: To get to the report properties you have to click on the background outside of the white report canvas (not very intuitive I know).  I have tried going the crosstab + RowGroup way setting by the expression to something like `=ceiling(rownumber(nothing)/3)` but had rotten luck.  Ignore the fact that this document it talking about making labels but note how it makes a single column into multiple: [Link](http://www.bscichicago.com/documents/CreatingAvery5160MailingLabelsSSRS.pdf)

Comment: Yes I can see that !Thanks! I came to know about that option. I used this =ceiling(rownumber(nothing)/3) expression too and its displaying data in three columns too . But not parallel.